# Azure ML & Pandas: How to convert String to DateTime

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I've got a dataset at hand with a column of DateTime in String format, eg.

```
a = 'Tue Sep 22 1998 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'
```

and a is just a value from the column.

If I use Metadata Editor in Azure Machine Learning Studio, it won't work and will complain that it can't do the conversion (from String to DateTime). I guess it's something to do with the format. So I'm trying the following:

```
a = str(a)[:10]+','+str(a)[10:15]
#'Tue Sep 22, 1998'
```

Now .NET surely can do the conversion, I mean by method like Convert.ToDateTime(). However, when I visualized the output of the Python script, I found the String has been changed into 'Tue Sep 22, 1998 None,', which is quite weird. Anyone knows what's wrong with it? I'm attaching the excerpt of python code down below:

```
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):

  dataframe1['timestamp'] = dataframe1['timestamp'].apply(lambda a: str(a)[:10]+','+str(a)[10:15])

  return dataframe1,
```

Comment: Check out the following: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior. Mix this with .apply() on the series to convert to DateTimes.

Comment: @BenAllison You mean I convert it to DateTime in this step and Azure will be able to recognize it as a DateTime?

Answer (score 1):

I use Python for date format normalization. You have to change to string before returning a dataFrame because underlying R will thrown an exception

```
def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    import pandas as pd
    dates = pd.to_datetime(dataframe1['DATE'])
    dates = dates.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    dataframe1['DATE'] = dates
return dataframe1,
```

Then I use a Metadata Editor to change the type to DateTime